# How to detect if client system is 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: xcode, swift

How would one detect if a client system is 32 or 64 bit in Swift?

I wasn't able to find anything in documentation and I had a hard time finding a solution. Therefore posting the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a 64-bit environment, a `CGFloat` is the same size as a `Double`. In a 32-bit environment it is the same size as a `Float`. There's a constant `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` which is therefore `1` on a 64-bit system.

```
let bit = 32 + (32 * CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE)
```

Comment: Since `CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE` is an `Int32`, it might be nice to make `bit` an `Int`: `let bit = 32 + (32 * Int(CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE))`.It might also be nice to also declare a boolean like `let systemIs64Bit = (CGFLOAT_IS_DOUBLE == 1)`.

Comment: For completeness, you might want to `import CoreGraphics` before defining this.

Answer (score 9):

The size of `Int` is guaranteed to be the same as platform’s native word size. see [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_481).

So this should works:

```
let bit = sizeof(Int) * Int(BYTE_SIZE)
let is64bit = sizeof(Int) == sizeof(Int64)
let is32bit = sizeof(Int) == sizeof(Int32)
```

Comment: For Swift 3: MemoryLayout<Int>.size == MemoryLayout<Int32>.size

Answer (score 6):

swift 4
`let is64bit = Int.bitWidth == Int64.bitWidth`